# Utilizar archivo de texto o base de datos SQlite

Tags: android, archivo, sqlite

Tengo que guardar datos momentaneamente y para eso tengo dos opciones, utilizar archivos de texto o usar una base de datos SQlite.

¿Qué es más óptimo? Debido a que los datos los guardo entre fragments para luego enviarlos por mail. Este es el código utilizado para guardar y leer datos:

```
 private void writeDataToString (String nombre_archivo,String data) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try{
        //FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("encryptedNotePad.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(nombre_archivo, MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

        // Escribimos el String en el archivo
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();

    }catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String readDataFromString(String nombre_archivo)
{
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput(nombre_archivo);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

        char[] inputBuffer = new char[100];
        String s = "";

        int charRead;
        while((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0){
            // Convertimos los char a String
            String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
            s += readString;

            inputBuffer = new char[100];
        }

        isr.close();
        return s;

    }catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

En cuanto a la base de datos extiendo la clase SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: Tu pregunta se basa en opiniones. Aunque obviamente las búsquedas en base de datos son más rápidas que las búsquedas en archivos de texto. Pero, por otro lado, si lo que almacenas en texto son registros únicos, nada te impide hacerlo así. Al final la respuesta a tu pregunta será siempre una opinión. Es probable que tu pregunta termine cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Recuerda revisar [ask], tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones, depende de la cantidad de datos o como deseas administrar los datos, me parece que se necesita mas informaciòn, saludos.